# Remote connection to SQL server 2008 sp2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, tcp, remote-server

I built a window application in visual studio 2010. It is working fine at my computer. when I trying to run from another computer it gives me an 
Error: 
    A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to     SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

here some information : 
computer ip: 192.168.0.25
DNS - 192.168.0.12
instance - SQLEXPRESS

Connection string : String = "Data Source=192.168.0.12\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=fleetInfo;User ID=user; Password=user123;"

Im running SQL Server Management Studio 2008 SP2. I checked sql server configuration Manager. Everything is fine.
In configuration Manager> protocols for SQLEXPRESS > TCP/IP:
IP1 
IP address: 192.168.20.100
Port : null
IP ALL
Dynamic port : 1408
TCP port: null

I'm wondering what is wrong Im doing here.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you allowed access through the firewall on the SQL port for incoming and outgoing connections to the server?

Comment: a few things to try out -> http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

Comment: have you rebooted or restarted your SQL service after enabling connections and the protocols? also enable Named Pipes while you are in there. TCP is often just the transport.

Comment: I set the firewall enable for sql port 1433.

Comment: @MortenAnderson I read all content in that article. its seems to OK.

Comment: @FrankThomas I reboot every time when I changed. I also restart Pipes after u suggest but the same thing.

Comment: Guys, this is stupid question but, what IP address i should use with server instance? Just want make sure that im using right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application on the same server as the SQL Instance you will need to reference that SQL instance rather than the IP of the server so your connection string should look something like Connection string : String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=fleetInfo;User ID=user; Password=user123;" when it is compiled and put on the server. For you to run it locally it will still need to be like you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using dynamic ports so you will have to specify the port number (1408 in your case) in the connect string: `192.168.0.12,1408`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server configuration manager appears to indicate that your SQL Server's IP address is 192.168.20.100, not 192.168.0.12 which is in you connection string.

Also, the instructions in the SSWUG article couldn't have worked because it indicates to use the wrong adress in the telnet section.

So:

1. Check config manager on the server again and verify the IP address and port (port may have changed)
2. go to a command prompt (start / run / CMD.EXE) and type

   ```
   TELNET [ip address from config manager] [port from config manager]
   ```

Do you get a black screen (indicating successful connection) or a failure message?